# Understanding repetitions in Swig tutorial example

Tags: python, swig

I am new to learning swig. I am interested in calling C++ from Python on an Ubuntu machine.

I just started looking at the intro tutorial here http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html

Consider the interface file on that page `example.i` copied as is below.

```
 /* example.i */
 %module example
 %{
 /* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
 extern double My_variable;
 extern int fact(int n);
 extern int my_mod(int x, int y);
 extern char *get_time();
 %}

 extern double My_variable;
 extern int fact(int n);
 extern int my_mod(int x, int y);
 extern char *get_time();
```

Why is are the contents between the `%{ %}` repeated in the second half of the file? As given in the manual, http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Introduction_nn5

> The %{ %} block provides a location for inserting additional code,
>   such as C header files or additional C declarations, into the
>   generated C wrapper code.

But it doesn't address the point of the repetition in the example. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code between `%{` and `%}` is inserted verbatim in the generated SWIG wrapper, and is used to give the wrapper code access to the headers or declarations listed.

The code outside those markers instructs SWIG to make a wrapper for each of the declarations (or entire header files) listed.

If you left out `extern int fact(int n);` in the first portion, the wrapper, when compiled and linked to the source or library containing the function, wouldn't be able to access the function since the extern declaration would be missing.  If left out of the second portion, a wrapper wouldn't be generated to access it from the scripting language.

There is a shortcut:

```
%inline %{
...
%}
```

That instructs SWIG to both insert and wrap the declarations.